# How to use the methods of object, inside another object

Tags: java, oop, linked-list

I have a method in a a class called Polynomial. From the main method i have created an object of type polynomial to use this add method, but what i have done i have passed it as parameter another object type.

```
p.add(new Polynomial(new Term(-1, 1)));
```

I know that this creates an anonymous LinkedList. I created a method that returns a LinkedList of that Object Type Term so that i can use that object and its methods.

I wanted to know if there is another way to access the methods of that object that is inside another object.

This is a class assignment i am sure there is an easier way of doing this, but this is the way the professor wants it.

```
public void add(Polynomial p) {
    ListIterator<Term> toAddIterator = p.getTerms().listIterator();
    ListIterator<Term> thisIterator = terms.listIterator();
    Term termToAdd = toAddIterator.next();

    while (thisIterator.hasNext()) {
        Term current = thisIterator.next();
        if (current.getPower() > termToAdd.getPower()) {
        } else if (current.getPower() < termToAdd.getPower()) {
            thisIterator.previous();
            thisIterator.add(termToAdd);
            thisIterator.next();
            break;
        } else {
            thisIterator.previous().addIfSamePower(termToAdd);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have read your questions 3 times now. I'm not able to understand what you are asking. I do not see what your constructor for Polynomial class looks like. The add() method you have posted seems to be unrelated to your question. Please see [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry is my first post.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, the best way to call a method of object inside another object is to have the outer object implement the method, that will then call the method on inner object. That means that your outer class doesn't know "too much" (That there is an object inside outer object and that it implements given method).

In this example, since you pass an object created in this place, its ok to just create a reference to this object and pass that instead - since you already know that object exists. At least thats how I understand your question.